# @Value returns null

Tags: java, spring, properties, properties-file

I am trying to get a value from the properties file and below is my attempt to inject URL. Not sure if i am doing this correctly.

I already have something set for URL in the properties file and I am pretty sure my injection method is wrong, but I am a java newbie so I can't really figure out the solution.

```java
public class DatabaseHelperClass {
    static String URL;

    @Value("${databaseURL}")
    public void propertiesSetter(String URL) {
        DatabaseHelperClass.URL = URL;
    }

    public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException{


        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: access problem while loading");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        catch(InstantiationException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: unable to instantiate driver");
            System.exit(3);
        }




        System.out.print(URL);
        Connection connection = null;
        System.out.println();

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.print(connection);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: Is it related to Spring ?

Comment: what class does `Value` refer to? If it's spring, well then you cannot use it outside spring bean context

Comment: And if you're using Spring, you'd better use its support for DataSources instead of reinventing the wheel (badly).

Comment: Yes I am using spring and  I have multiple .properties file. Dev, test etc so I can't specify an absolute path to my properties file

Answer (score 0):

In **applicationContext.xml**, you have to add your properties file to be read from the class path :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:something.properties, classpath:demo.properties" />
```

If you want to add multiple properties file, just add by separating it with a comma

Update your class like this :

```
public class DatabaseHelperClass {

  @Value("${databaseURL}")
  static String URL;


public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException{


    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: access problem while loading");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    catch(InstantiationException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to instantiate driver");
        System.exit(3);
    }




    System.out.print(URL);
    Connection connection = null;
    System.out.println();

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        System.out.print(connection);
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: xml config in 2019? Ewwwww

Comment: so i am using spring but I have multi .properties file. One for test one fore dev etc, so i dont think <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:something.properties" /> is going to work in this case

Comment: You can add multiple properties files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring framework I assume, simply writing @Value annotation will not work. You have to write a calls which helps in identify the properties file names. I provide below an example.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource("file:config/credentials-config.properties"),
  @PropertySource("file:config/app-config.properties")
})
public class ConfigReader {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```